# Oscillatory time-series forecasting

Tags: time-series, forecasting, prediction

I was wondering if this mean(160)-reverting/oscillatory time series "SUM" can be considered chaotic & forecastable to some extend short-term?

http://sg.myfreepost.com/sgTOTO_analysispower.php?draws=60&fn0=Sum

Are there time-series forecasting methods that give a broader "range" prediction structure rather than "exact/precise" future numbers (e.g, neural network which can be totally off since it is just trying to curve-fit)? 
Is fuzzy logic method able to give a prediction interval for the immediate next period in a discrete time series?

I would appreciate if anyone can provide some insight to this case study.

Comment: How is fuzzy logic applied to time series forecasting in general? Is anyone familiar with ANFIS?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/products/fuzzy-logic/examples.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/fuzzy/mgtsdemo.html

Comment: I don't think I completely got your question. But Gaussian Processes [1] give a prediction performance estimate through the covariance matrix.

[1] http://www.gaussianprocess.org/